# Legend disappears in QGIS 2.8 composer

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer

I would like to keep my legend on as I export a multipage map set to PDF, but the legend appears to lose any layer items and just keep the title ("Legend"), which is what appears in my PDF document.

My map set in Composer has 12 pages, 8 of which contain similar content: a map window with different views of the same extent for each page, a legend that is set to the correct map window on each page, a scale bar for each map window, and title and descriptive text. Each legend has a sequential ID value from 1 to 8 ("Legend 1" ... "Legend 8") and is filtered to viewable layers.

I am running QGIS 2.8 on Windows 7. All my layers are shapefiles.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the cause of your specific problem but I discovered a bug regarding printing legends in the general case for which I found a work-around.

When printing a single map with legend, if the box "lock layer styles for map item" is checked, then the legend does not print when exported in PDF or any other form of printing the map.  In order to print the legend, it is necessary to unclick that box (and then refix your layer styles if necessary).

Hope that helps and I hope the bug can be easily fixed so we can take full advantage of the feature locking styles.